# unitary matrix with an unusual constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups

(1) I am interesting in finding a rank 3 unitary matrix $U$ satisfying
$$
U U^*=-1=-\text{diag}(1,1,1).
$$
$$
U U^\dagger=+1=+\text{diag}(1,1,1).
$$

(2) I am interesting in finding a rank 4 unitary matrix $U$ satisfying
$$
U U^*=-1=-\text{diag}(1,1,1,1).
$$
$$
U U^\dagger=+1=+\text{diag}(1,1,1,1).
$$

Here $*$ for complex conjugate, and the $\dagger$ for complex conjugate then transpose.

This question is secondary, or not necessary if you can answer (1) and (2):

(3) I wonder what are the generic properties of such $U$? Can it be embed into some continuous Lie group? [part of $U(N)$?]

Comment: What's the difference between $U^*$ and $U^\dagger$? Do they not both denote the conjugate transpose?

Comment: I do not think (1) is possible: In 3-D $\det(UU^*)=|\det U|^2=1$ cannot be the same as $\det(-\mathbb{I})=-1$.

Comment: Thanks, $*$ for complex conjugate, and the $\dagger$ for complex conjugate then transpose.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be the rank of $U$. For $n=3$ (or $n$ odd in general) there is no solution as the determinant of $UU^*$ cannot be negative. For $n$ even there are many solutions. For example, for $n=4$, the following $U$, with $\theta$ and $\phi$ arbitrary angles, satisfies the requirements of (2):

$$U=\begin{pmatrix}
0&-e^{i\theta}&0&0\\
e^{i\theta}&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&-e^{i\phi}\\
0&0&e^{i\phi}&0\\
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$

What you want is a $U$ with the following property: if $v$ is an eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $e^{i\chi}$, then $v^*$ should be also and eigenvector of $U$ with eigenvalue $-e^{i\chi}$.

Comment: Thanks Anders, but I am not sure $UU^* \neq -1$ in your example?

Comment: In the example $U^*$ looks the same as $U$ but with a negative sign in the exponents. Do the matrix multiplication and you should get the desired $UU^*=-1$.